# Numbering of tcbtheorem references

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, environments, labels

For my document, I like to have all my theorem environments be counted consecutively as definition 1, definition 2, ..., theorem 1, theorem 2, ....

I created a tcb theorem environment that does this, however, whenever I reference a theorem it only gives the section + subsection that theorem is under.

```
\documentclass[reqno, 11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor={red!50!black}
}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter]{thm}{Theorem}
{theorem style=plain,colframe=red!50!black,colback=red!5!white,
coltitle=red!50!black,fonttitle=\upshape\bfseries,fontupper=\itshape,boxrule=0.5pt}{}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
    \subsection{Subsection One} \hfill
        \begin{thm}{Theorem 1 Name}{} \label{thm:1}
            Theorem here
        \end{thm}
        \begin{thm}{Theorem 2 name}{} \label{thm:2}
            Theorem here 
        \end{thm}
By Theorem ~\ref{thm:1}, ... By Theorem ~\ref{thm:2},...
\end{document}
```

In this example, the reference renders the 1.1 for both Theorems 1 and 2. I would like it to render 1 for Theorem 1 and 2 for Theorem 2. I obviously would like this to not reset when going into another section.

Comment: use the label key: `\begin{thm}[label=thm:1]{Theorem 1 Name}{} `

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Not really…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument in your theorem environment, which you left empty, is actually for a label. You can specify a prefix like `thm` when you define your theorem environment (the last argument, which you also left empty) so you don't have to repeat it in every label:

```
\documentclass[reqno, 11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{nameref}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor={red!50!black}
}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter]{thm}{Theorem}
{theorem style=plain,colframe=red!50!black,colback=red!5!white,
coltitle=red!50!black,fonttitle=\upshape\bfseries,fontupper=\itshape,boxrule=0.5pt}{thm}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
    \subsection{Subsection One} \hfill
        \begin{thm}{Theorem 1 Name}{duck}
            Theorem here
        \end{thm}
        \begin{thm}{Theorem 2 name}{bear}
            Theorem here 
        \end{thm}
By Theorem ~\ref{thm:duck}, ... By Theorem ~\ref{thm:bear},...
\end{document}
```